# Oracle Form (FMB) to XML, what is dirtyinfo

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

When you convert an FMB to XML it has an attribute on the formmodule, blocks and items called DirtyInfo.

I was just wondering, what is this attribute and what option does it relate to on the property palette.

Comment: I don't know, and don't know of any documentation for it. Might be something to do with how the block and items are checked for state changes (e.g. how it decides whether the form is "dirty" and has changes waiting to be saved). Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know the "DirtyInfo" shows if a property has been modified. This will also be set when the particular property has been manually set back to its default value.

If you select a property of an item and change it, a small green square will be shown on the left side of the property which I think shows its DirtyInfo. If this item is **not** subclassed and you press the button "inherit" (located at the top of the properties window) the items property will get set back to its default value and the green square vanishes (and shouldn't be shown as dirty anymore).